# How can I change the default SQLite timezone

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

How can I change the default SQLite timezone?
When inserting my records, i want SQlite to use a `+3:30` timezone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

None of [SQLite's supported date formats](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime) contains a time zone. Generally, dates are assumed to be in UTC; there is no 'default' time zone.

It is possible to convert date values between UTC and the local time zone, or to add a fixed offset to timestamps, but the results still do not have a time zone mark, so you should do this only if you are going to format timestamps for displaying.

To do more time zone handling than SQLite supports, you have to handle this in your app's Java code.

Comment: was very useful. . .

Comment: But how does SQLite figure out the local timezone?

Comment: @MarcelHernandez By asking the OS.

Answer (score 1):

The [Answer by CL.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37620022/642706) is correct, and should be accepted.

As said there, you should do time zone handling in your Java code using the excellent java.time framework.

## java.time

The [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes are built into Java 8 and later. Much of their functionality has been back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project, and further adapted to Android in the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project.

The java.time classes are the successor to the highly successful Joda-Time library, both projects led by the same man, [Stephen Colbourne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38896/jodastephen). The java.time classes supplant the notoriously troublesome old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java.

### UTC

Best practice is usually to do your business logic, data storage, and data exchange all in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). Most databases store date-times in UTC. As noted SQLite (being “lite”) has no support for time zone, so you should adjust your date-time values into UTC for insertion into SQLite.

For this reason and other reasons, programmers should learn to think in UTC while on the job.

### Offset from UTC

If you are sure you want to use an offset of `+03:30`, use the [`ZoneOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html)  and [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) classes. By the way, always use a leading zero on the hour, `+03:30` not `+3:30`; common by convention, and required by some software and protocols.

```
ZoneOffset zoneOffset = ZoneOffset.of( 3 , 30 );
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.of( 2016 , 1 , 2 , 12 , 0 , 0 , 0 , zoneOffset );  // Noon on Jan 2 in offset `+03:30`.
```

### Time zone

A time zone is an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) *plus* a set of rules of adjusting for anomalies such as [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time). If you know the intended time zone, generally best to use it rather than a mere offset. For example, `Asia/Tehran`. Use `ZoneId` and `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tehran" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( 2016 , 1 , 2 , 12 , 0 , 0 , 0 , zoneId ); // Noon on Jan 2 in Iran.
```

### `Instant` for UTC

To work with you database switch to UTC. An `Instant` is a moment on the timeline in UTC with a resolution of nanoseconds. We can extract an `Instant` object from either of our date-time objects discussed above.

```
Instant instant = odt.toInstant();  
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant();
```

### JDBC

If your JDBC driver complies with JDBC 4.2 ([JSR 221](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221), [Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/jdbc_42.html), [java.sql package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/package-summary.html)), you may be able to use the `Instant` object directly by passing to [`setObject`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject-int-java.lang.Object-) on your [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( instant , 1 );
```

If that does not work with your JDBC driver, fall back to using the old `java.sql` types. For a date-time that means [`java.sql.Timestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) and its [`from( Instant )`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#from-java.time.Instant-) method.

```
java.sql.Timestamp ts = java.sql.Timestamp.from( instant );
myPreparedStatement.setTimestamp( ts , 1 );
```